# Converting SQL query to LINQ -- Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am having issue converting a SQL query into LINQ. I think I have 95% of it replicated into LINQ however having issue on a join

SQL

```
SELECT 
    table1.Column1 
FROM 
    table 1 table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    table 2 table2 ON table2.Column1 = table1.Column1 
                   AND table2.Column2 = 1838 
WHERE 
    table1.Column2 = 1 
    AND table1.Column3 = 24029 
    AND (table2.[Column3] IS NULL OR table2.[Column3] = 1)
```

LINQ so far

```
var query = from table1 in table 1
            join table2 in table 2 on table1.Column1 equals table2.Column1 && table2.Column2 == 1838 into result
            from table2 in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where table1.Column2 == 1 && table1.Column3 == 24029 && (table2.Column3 == null || table2.Column3 == 1)
            select table1.Column1;
```

When I run the query I get an error at this line

```
join table2 in table 2 on table1.Column1 equals table2.Column1 && tabl2.Column2 == 1838 into result
```

Error:

> CS0019 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The best advice is - don't. LINQ is just a query language. *Entity Framework* on the other hand, is an *ORM*. It maps *objects* to tables. Create proper *entities* with relations and navigation properties and EF will generate the JOIN statements.

Comment: Assuming your entities are Order and LineItem, each LineItem could have an Order property. An Order should have a `LineItems` collection. If you wanted to load an order and all line items, you could simply load the order. Its LineItems would be loaded with it

Comment: This `From table 1 table1` does not look valid.  Neither does `from table 1 in table 1`.  There cannot be spaces in names like that.  Also `table2.Column2 = 1838` should really be in the where cause, not the on clause of the join in the sql and absolutely cannot be there in the Linq join.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't really fix the entire problem.  I'd expect the SQL to be something like `From [table 1] table1` and the Linq to be `from t1 in table_1` instead.

Comment: `table2.Column2 = 1838` is perfectly fine within an SQL join, and can have a large performance impact on complex queries. It is best to test the various methods of joins with a Query Analyzer to see if there are any performance benefits.
You could also simplify the last line of the SQL  `AND (table2.[Column3] IS NULL OR table2.[Column3] = 1)` to `AND (IsNull(table2.[Column3],1) = 1)`

Answer (score 4):

The LINQ syntax for [composite key join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx) is different. So instead of incorrect

```
join table2 in table_2 on table1.Column1 equals table2.Column1 && table2.Column2 == 1838 into result
```

you could use something like this

```
join table2 in table_2
on new { table1.Column1, Column2 = 1838 } equals new { table2.Column1, table2.Column2 }
into result
```

Comment: Hmm... Is that a "deep equals" or merely a reference equals?

Comment: @RobertHarvey C# anonoymous types have value comparison semantics. The same technique is used for group by composite key, so apparently it would not work if it was reference equality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Also in this case it's presumable being turned into SQL anyway.

Comment: @juharr Good point. In such case the alternative `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax with `from t2 in table2.Where(....).DefaultIfEmpty()` could be the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Linq is more strict than SQL when it comes to the on clause of a join.  Basically it compares the stuff on one side of the `equals` to the other side.  `equals` is not like `==` and you cannot chain more logic to the end with logical operators.  The best approach is to just put the columns that form the relationship between the tables into the on clause of the join.

```
join table2 in table_2 on table1.Column1 equals table2.Column1 into result
```

Then move the `table2.Column2 == 1838` to the `where`

```
where table2.Column2 == 1838
      && table1.Column2 == 1 
      && table1.Column3 == 24029 
      && (table2.Column3 == null || table2.Column3 == 1)
```

Alternatively this would also work, but really isn't best practice.

```
join table2 in table_2 
on new {table1.Column1, Column2 = 1838} 
equals new {table2.Column1, table2.Column2 } into result
```

As that is how you do multiple comparisons, but note it will only do equality unlike SQL that would allow you to do any type of logical clause.

Alternatively if you use EF and the tables have a foreign key relationship you should have navigation properties and you can do something like

```
from table1 in table_1
from table2 in table1.table_2s.DefaultIfEmpty()
....
```

Comment: Thanks @juharr for the explanation and correction. So got the idea that only one equal is allowed in the join statement. I shall try moving it to the where clause and see if I can get the same results. Also thanks for the advice regarding EF I will look into that.

Comment: One question though, why do we not require to put the table reference name in this line for the second column `on new {table1.Column1, Column2 = 1838} `?

Comment: @Kevin In that case we are creating a anonymous class and the value of the second property is 1838 and the name is `Column2` so it will match the other anonymous class.  Basically if you reference a property in an anonymous class it will take that property name, but for constant values you have to name the property.  So another way of writing that would be `new { Column1 = table1.Column1, Column2 = 1838} 
equals new { Column1 = table2.Column1, Column2 = table2.Column2 }`

Comment: @Kevin  If the properties on the tables have different names you'd have to give the anonymous classes the same name, something like `new { Column1 = table1.Table1Id, Column2 = 1838} equals new { Column1 = table2.RefTable1Id, Column2 = table2.Column2 }`